# Query if null value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I have multiple variables that can be null, is there a better way to construct a mysql query to deal  with "is null"?

```
DB::connection('mysql')->select('select * from db where width = ? and height = ? and length = ? and color = ?', [$width, $height, $length, $color]);
```

Instead of

```
if ($width == null) {
  DB::connection('mysql')->select('select * from db where width is null and height = ? and length = ? and color = ?',[$height, $length, $color]);
}elseif($height == null) {
...
```

Comment: If you switched to using the builder rather than raw statements then you could use conditional statements to power this...

Comment: you're right! If I use query builder, I don't have to worry about conditional null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might not use your table. But I have stumbled upon this too long time ago. In my example I use model, an array of column name and column value.

The array:

```
$filterData = [
  'width' => 21.0,
  'height' => 11.5,
  'length' => null
];
```

The query:

```
$mainQuery = Furniture::where($filterData);
```

To see the output: `$mainQuery->toSql();`

Comment: Indeed your way is more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Using query builder solved my problem. It automatically change the query to "is null" when the variable is null.

```
DB::connection('mysql')->table('db')->where('width', $width)->where('height', $height)->where('length', $length)->where('color', $color)->get();
```